# Queue consumer suddenly returns NO message even messages in the queue

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

**UPDATE 2**

Scenario below:

1 Consumer is reading messages from queue successfully,

2 For some reason, Consumer returns no message even when lots of messages are in the queue. This lasts a few hours on some occasions, where Producers can continue sending messages.

Existing remaining messages in the queue are en-queued by more than one commit by Producers. The number of messages can be from one to a few hundreds.

This issue happens occasionally, and once it happens, Consumer always returns no message until after the app is restarted.

The code below is simplified, which is ran by one thread from thread pool threads at a time in point.

```
thread entry
    Open(ConnectionMode.Read); 
loop when it is not cancelled
        var message = GetMessage();           
        queueManager.Commit();     
Loop end

        queue.Close();           
        queueManager.Disconnect();
thread exit    

      public string GetMessage()
        {
            const int MaxMessageSizeInBytes = 8000;
            const int ReadTimeoutInMilliseconds = 3000;

            message = new MQMessage { Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING };
            var mqMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions
            {
                WaitInterval = ReadTimeoutInMilliseconds,
                Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING
                | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT  //use syncpoint for consumer acknowledgment
            };

            var content = message.ReadString(message.MessageLength);
            message.ClearMessage();

            return content;
        }

        public IMessage Get()
        {
            var mqMessage = new MQMessage { Format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING };
            var mqMessageOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions
            {
                WaitInterval = ReadTimeoutInMilliseconds,
                Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | MQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT
            };

            Connection.MqQueue.Get(mqMessage, mqMessageOptions, MaxMessageSizeInBytes);

            return mqMessage.MapToMessage();
        }


        public void Open(connectionMode connectionMode)
        {
            var connectionSettings = new Hashtable
            {
                {MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED },
                {MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT }
            };

            int openOptions = 0;

            switch (connectionMode)
            {
                case connectionMode.Read:
                    openOptions = MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                    break;
                case connectionMode.Write:
                    openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
                    break;
            }


            MqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(_queueManagerName, connectionSettings);
            MqQueue = MqQueueManager.AccessQueue(_queueName, openOptions);
        }
```

MQ Server V8 on Windows

.NET Client: 8.0.0.5

Comment: If the application that put the messages on the queue has not issued a commit then your application cannot retrieve them.  Yes, the queue depth will be greater than zero but the messages are unavailable.

Comment: But after Consumer restarts, it can see messages. It contradicts to the explanation that messages have not been committed by Producers? Please explain.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated my post. Please check.